# Passing Enum to constructor as string

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass an enum into a constructor of `Movie()` at

```
Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", MovieGenre.Action, 8, 2000 );
```

but getting this error:

> Can not Convert from 'UserQuery.MovieGenre' to 'string'

What am I doing wrong and how I can fix this?

```
void Main()
{
    enum MovieGenre{
        Action,
        Horor,
        Drama,
        Comedy,
        Thriller
    }
    Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", MovieGenre.Action, 8, 2000 );
}

class Movie
{

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Movie( string title, string genre, int rank, int year ){
     Title = title;
     Genre = genre;
     Rank = rank;
     Year = year;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know `MovieGenre.Action` is an `int`, right?

Comment: `MovieGenre.Horor` is misspelled by the way, 2 "r"'s, "Horror"

Comment: @mona, Please see my version of your code snippet within my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", MovieGenre.Action.ToString(), 8, 2000 );
```

:), or

```
public Movie( string title, MovieGenre genre, int rank, int year ){
```

EDIT:
Here's is your snippet. (formatting is screwed, can't figure it out)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", MovieGenre.Action, 8, 2000 );
  }
}

public enum MovieGenre
{
  Action,
  Horror,
  Drama,
  Comedy,
  Thriller
}

public class Movie
{

public string Title { get; set; }
public MovieGenre Genre { get; set; }
public int Rank { get; set; }
public int Year { get; set; }
public Movie( string title, MovieGenre genre, int rank, int year ){
 Title = title;
 Genre = genre;
 Rank = rank;
 Year = year;
}
```

}

Comment: Simon Wilson's 2nd suggestion is the better option.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Simon but I am getting error on second option

Comment: Because you have to move the enum out of the Main() method and make it public

Comment: Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type is less accessible than method

Comment: but now I am getting a new error on `Main()`  here it is `The name 'MovieGenre' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Hold on, I'll rewrite your snippet for you

Comment: Thanks a lots so the `enum` is not inside the `Movie` class scope?

Comment: No. Though you could put it within the class, then it would be referenced as `Movie.MovieGenre.Horror` I prefer non nested enums myself.

Comment: Thanks again, it was very helpful